# Which AI algorithm is great for mapping between two XML files

Tags: machine-learning, problem-solving, genetic-programming

My work colleague got a project with a lot of work that is not hard or complicated.  The problem is simple but it is a lot of work. 
We have two XML files with a lot of variables in it. Not only is the XML files flatten but you would have classes with classes in them that can reach an absurd amount of depth.

The problem comes in that the one file is a request that is received and the other is a response. The request needs to map its variables to the response variables. A simple tool could be built to solve this solution but the problem comes in that there are rules for certain variables. Some variables in the request have arithmetic involve, sometimes with other variables, or some don't get mapped if other variables are present.

I was thinking about Genetic Programming when I heard about this problem. If all the rules could be defined then it should be able to build a tree that would represent the desired output which is the XML response.

Will it work and if not do you think there is an AI algorithm that can solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard tool to work with XML files is XSLT. You may not need AI to solve this problem. But.. you have to learn how to program with XSLT ;)
On Windows you can use MSXML, if you work from C++ - msxsl.exe, C# has internal supoort for XSLT. That is what I know about. There are also non-MS tools.